# Entity framework core - DbUpdateException

Tags: entity-framework, exception

UPDATED: I have a piece of code that creates records when they don't exist, or updates them when they do exist. However, while trying to update the records I get this exception:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException The DELETE statement
>   conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint

```
public static string AddCurrencies(ApplicationDbContext db)
{
    // ...

    foreach (Currency c in db.Currency.ToList())
    {
        try
        {
            db.Remove(c); // the troublemaker!
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch
        {
            // probably in use (foreign key)
        }
    }

    // ...

    foreach (Currency c in CurrencyList)
    {
        var c_db = db.Currency.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Code == c.Code);
        if (c_db == null)
        {
            // adding
            db.Currency.Add(c);
        }
        else
        {
            // updating
            c_db.Name = c.Name;
            c_db.LocalDisplay = c.LocalDisplay;
        }
        db.SaveChanges(); // exception fired if updating!
    }

    // ...
}
```

After some investigation, and having being able to turn SQL debugging on, I found out that the Remove() "persists" and that it will be retried with the second call to SaveChanges(), hence the exception. Now the question is reformulated: how do I "undo" (in the lack of a better expression) the Remove() commands that failed?

Comment: Is Name the key of Currency? [Examine the generated SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx) for clues.

Comment: No, Name is not the key. | db.Database.Log => Cannot assign to 'Log' because it is a 'method group'

Comment: Add this before SaveChanges(): `db.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);`  then look at debugger output

Comment: Also, is your CurrencyList being tracked under EF?

Comment: I can't use this code because I don't have access to **Log** method. Also, I access directly DbSet and don't use AsNoTracking(), so I suppose tracking is on.

Comment: Sorry, they changed it for core http://rion.io/2016/10/19/accessing-entity-framework-core-queries-behind-the-scenes-in-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue this way:

```
var entry = context.Entry(entity);
entry.Reload();
```

for each entry where delete failed.